# como conseguir la lista de videos de un usuario en youtube

Tags: javascript, html

Hola estaba intentando conseguir la lista de mis videos para no hacerlo manualmente. leí en algun artículo que hicieron sobre una manera simple de hacerlo. el thread es:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613903/youtube-api-v3-get-list-of-users-videos

arranco el código pero no muestra nada.

El código:

```
<html>
<script>
// Get Uploads Playlist
$.get(
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
   part : 'contentDetails', 
   forUsername : 'USER_CHANNEL_NAME',
   key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
   function(data) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
          getVids(pid);
      });
  }
);

//Get Videos
function getVids(pid){
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
        part : 'snippet', 
        maxResults : 20,
        playlistId : pid,
        key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
        function(data) {
            var results;
            $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                results = '<li>'+ item.snippet.title +'</li>';
                $('#results').append(results);
            });
        }
    );
}

</script>
<!--In your HTML -->
<ul id="results"></ul>
</html>
```

Como podría hacerlo para obtener la lista de videos y guardarlo en mi fichero o añadirlos y luego mostrarlos.

Comment: Estás poniendo código JavaScript (jQuery) dentro de una etiqueta PHP... No te va a funcionar jamás así.. Ese código lo tiene que interpretar el cliente, no el servidor.

Comment: Eso es Javascript, no es PHP. Si quieres hacerlo con PHP u otro tienes que autorizar la API de Youtube en la Consola de proyectos de Google, luego tienes que instalar la librería de la API, con `Composer` preferiblemente en el caso de PHP ([ver guía de inicio](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=es-419)) y luego escribir el código PHP [tal y como se explica aquí](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=es-419). En ese mismo enlace te explican paso por paso lo que tienes que hacer.

Comment: lo puse en html y configure pero aun así no devuelve el resultado.

Comment: @SergioRamos y remplazaste los valores de usuario y key?

Comment: Sergio ¿tienes autorizada la API de YouTube en tu proyecto, como se indica en la guía de inici? (ver primer enlace de mi comentario anterior).

Comment: si la añadi key: 'YOUR_API_KEY' puse mi key y en usuario puse mi email.